# breadcrumbs using django admin templates

Tags: django, admin, breadcrumbs

I have created a site mainly using django's admin interface, plus a few custom views. As the majority of the site is using the admin (and I am not to hot with css), I have just used django's admin tempates for my custom views (they are extended generic views).

Anyway, most of my custom views look good, and match the look and feel of the admin interface, but I don't know how to get the breadcrumbs working.

So form an extended generic view, how and what do I pass to the tempate's

```
    {% block breadcrumb %}
```

tag?

I saw one article that mentioned the context object, but didn't have any further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide breadcrumbs in your template and get breadcrumbs from parent template you can use block breadcrumbs & block.super variable in it:

```
{% block breadcrumbs %}{{ block.super }} &rsaquo; My custom site{% endblock %}
```

Or just pass to the template variable *title*.